# Python Mongo DB query returns wrong results when used on string fields that stores ISODate format dates

Tags: python, mongodb, isodate

My Mongo DB has documents with structure like below (just made-up values, not actual values):

```
{
_id: ObjectId("1")
other_fields: "values1"
people: Array
  0: Object
    NAME: John
    SCHEDULED_DATE: "2017-05-03T12:00:00.000Z"
  1: Object
    NAME: Mary
    SCHEDULED_DATE: "2017-06-03T11:00:00.000Z"
}
```

In each document, there is a sub-document called people.  people is an array of objects.  Each of these "people" object has a SCHEDULED_DATE field which is of STRING type but the value stored inside is in fact a ISODate format.

I tried to query with below condition.

```
db.collection.find(
  {'people.SCHEDULED_DATE': {'$gt': '2017-11-01', '$lt': '2017-11-30'}}
)
```

The query returns 8 records, 7 of which do have people.SCHEDULED_DATE in November.  However, there is also one document returned where all the SCHEDULED_DATE fields inside all the "people" sub-documents are not in November.

I have tried this query with different date ranges and I have tried with different combination of {"$gt", "$lt"}, {"$gte", "$lte"}, etc.  Still some irrelevant records would be returned.

I know I can store things in ISODate() format in the DB.  But this DB is storing things directly obtained from a 3rd party and there is a reason we could not change the format.

Questions:
1. Why did the query return records where all people.SCHEDULED_DATE are not in the range?
2. Is there an elegant solution to my problem?  i.e. query people.SCHEDULED_DATE (string format) with a range of dates

Comment: Is the collection very big? Because what one thing that comes to mind is iterating the collection and parse the `people.SCHEDULED_DATE` from the string it's stored as into a Python date, and then compare (though indeed: this would have to be done on a record-by-record basis). Otherwise, how about running a task (every night or whatever) that creates a copy of the collection (into a new collection, I mean) with the `SCHEDULED_DATE` stored as an actual date (not as a string)? I think I'd go with this second approach. That way, you can use Mongo's `$gt` and `$lt` properly

Comment: Thanks @BorrajaX. I have tried to iterate through the records and do a string comparison in the loop.  It did work and that was the current approach used in the program.  I just wanted to know why the native find() would sometimes return results not matching the conditions, while most of the records are correct.